# How to create forced scrolling to anchors on a website on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, web-frontend

I have a site where I have each section as 100vh so it fills the height of the screen perfectly. The next step I wanted to implement was disabling the regular scrolling, and on scroll force the screen to jump smoothly to the top of the next 100vh section. Here is the example of this animation / feature:

https://www.quay.com.au/

I was having a hard time finding any answers for this as most things just deal with smooth scrolling when clicking on anchors, not actually forcing div relocation when the user scrolls up / down.

I just wanted to know what code I would need do this...

Thanks, been using stack overflow for a while but first post, let me know if there is anything I can do to make this more clear.

Comment: Please insert your [code](/help/mcve) to your question! Without code it's hard to help you.

Comment: On a side note, you might wanna consider how scroll hijacking will affect the  websites ux.  Just a friendly tip :) [worth reading](https://buildcreate.com/why-scroll-hijacking-destroys-user-experience/)

Comment: why do you need to force div relocation? technically you can just have a JS code to track the scrolling, and if it exceeds a certain threshold, then use one of the smooth scrolling libraries to "scroll" to an anchor

Comment: @Samleo that sounds good, I'll give that a try, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** this solution needs some testing and probably a bit of improvements, but works for me

if you don't want to use a plugin and prefer a vanilla JavaScript solution I hacked together a small example how this can be achieved with JS features in the following codepen:

https://codepen.io/lehnerchristian/pen/QYPBbX

but the main part is:

```
function(e) {
  console.log(e);

  const delta = e.deltaY;

  // check which direction we should scroll
  if (delta > 0 && currentlyVisible.nextElementSibling) {
    // scroll downwards
    currentlyVisible = currentlyVisible.nextElementSibling;
  } else if (delta < 0 && currentlyVisible.previousElementSibling) {
    // scroll upwards
    currentlyVisible = currentlyVisible.previousElementSibling;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  // perform scroll
  currentlyVisible.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

what it does is that it listens for the wheel event and then calls the callback, which intercepts the scroll event. inside the callback the direction is determined and then `Element.scrollIntoView()` is called to let the browser do the actual scrolling

check https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollintoview for browser support, if you're going for this solution